# Azure Cosmos Db as key value store indexing mode

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

What indexing mode / policy should I use when using cosmos db as a simple key/value store?

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy :

> None: Indexing is disabled on the container. This is commonly used when a container is used as a pure key-value store without the need for secondary indexes.

Is this because the property used as partition key is indexed even when indexMode is set to “none”? I would expect to need to turn indexing on but specify just the partition key’s path as the only included path.

If it matters, I’m planning to use the SQL API.

EDIT:

here's the information I was missing to understand this:

1. The item must have an `id` property, otherwise cosmos db will assign one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/account-databases-containers-items#properties-of-an-item
2. Since I'm using Azure Data Factory to load the items, I can tell ADF to duplicate the column that has the value I want to use as my id into a new column called `id`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy
3. I need to use `ReadItemAsync`, or better yet, `ReadItemStreamAsync` since it doesn't deserialize the response, to get the item without using a query.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.readitemasync?view=azure-dotnet
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.readitemstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `indexingMode` to `"none"`, the only way to efficiently retrieve a document is by `id` (e.g. `ReadDocumentAsync()` or `read_item()`). This is akin to a key/value store, since you wouldn't be performing queries against other properties; you'd be specifically looking up a document by some known id, and returning the entire document. Cost-wise, this would be ~1RU for a 1K document, just like point-reads with an indexed collection.

You could still run queries, but without indexes, you'll see unusually-high RU cost.

You would still specify the partition key's value with your point-reads, as you'd normally do.

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but how do I know the document id if documents are loaded by something like azure data factory? Can I make document id equal to the value of the partition key? For example, if I use property `AccountId` as the PK, will documentId be:
`UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, "account-id-value")`

Comment: Also, is there an effecient way to retrieve using the SQL API (with indexingMode = none)?

Comment: If you don’t know the document ID and need to search by something else, then you should probably enable indexing. If you know Account ID, then perhaps use Account ID for your ID (just be careful of duplicates). But if you really need to query properties other than ID, you may just want to leave indexing on and take advantage of the benefits.

Comment: it looks like I can accomplish this by telling ADF to duplicate the AccountId column as a new column called `id`, didn't realize that I need to use a column called `id` for this :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimentation on this and created a collection with indexing policy

```
{
    "indexingMode": "none",
    "automatic": false
}
```

Into that I inserted 100,003 documents of the following form

```
string id, string partitionKey, string someValue.
```

- There were 50,001 documents with `id` of `"id"` and partitionKey from `"0"` to `"50000"` inclusive.
- There were 50,001 documents with `id` of `"id2"` and partitionKey from `"0"` to `"50000"` inclusive.
- There was one document with `id` of `"id3"` and partitionKey of `"0"`.

I tried the following queries

```
--50001 matching documents
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM c
WHERE c.id = 'id'

--One matching document
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM c
WHERE c.id = 'id3'

--Two matching documents
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM c
where c.partitionKey = '2'
```

The query execution stats were not identical but pretty much the same for all the above (ordered as per the queries)

| RU | Partition key range id | Retrieved document count | Retrieved document size (in bytes) | Output document count | Output document size (in bytes) | Index hit document count | Index lookup time (ms) | Document load time (ms) | Query engine execution time (ms) | System function execution time (ms) | User defined function execution time (ms) | Document write time (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3,266.10 | 0 | 100003 | 29728669 | 1 | 82 | 0 | 0 | 190.74 | 23.40 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3,114.31 | 0 | 100003 | 29728669 | 2 | 156 | 0 | 0 | 197.32 | 21.85 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3,398.89 | 0 | 100003 | 29728669 | 2 | 156 | 0 | 0 | 199.26 | 23.84 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Trying

```
--One matching document
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM c
where c.partitionKey = '2' and c.id = 'id'
```

Gave a request charge of `5.62 RUs` and stats of

| Stat | Value |
| --- | --- |
| RU | 5.62 |
| Partition key range id | 0 |
| Retrieved document count | 1 |
| Retrieved document size (in bytes) | 293 |
| Output document count | 1 |
| Output document size (in bytes) | 78 |
| Index hit document count | 1 |
| Index lookup time (ms) | 0 |
| Document load time (ms) | 0.06 |
| Query engine execution time (ms) | 0.01 |
| System function execution time (ms) | 0 |
| User defined function execution time (ms) | 0 |
| Document write time (ms) | 0 |

So it looks like neither `id` or the partition key have any useful indexing on their own. Both need to be supplied.

Likely the `5.62` RU cost above would have been reduced if I used the SDK and did an actual point read rather than just using queries in data explorer.